# C# Wait for value to be set

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I am using a Skiasharp canvas where I draw a circle. Now the color of the circle gets decided by a webcall, so I use this code in the beginning:

```
public DeviceControl()
{
    NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
    InitializeComponent();

    ColorHandler();
}

public Task ColorHandler(string Type)
{
    return GetColors();
}

private async Task GetColors()
{
    colorList= await App.RestService.GetColors();
    pickerMode.ItemsSource = colorList;
    selectedColor = colorList.Where(x => x.Id == myCircle.ColorId).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Then after this code the app will draw the Canavas in the following void:

```
private void OnCanvasViewPaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
{
    SKCanvas canvas = e.Surface.Canvas;
    float UnscaledWidth = e.Info.Width;
    float UnscaledHeight = e.Info.Height;

    if (selectedColor != null)
    {
        imgLedstrip.Foreground = selectedColor;
    }
    else
    {
        imgLedstrip.Foreground = Color.FromHex("#707070");
    }

    /* REST OF MY CODE, BUT IRRELEVANT */
}
```

But the variable selectedColor is empty, while it gets filled later on!!!

Why is my constructor not awaiting the CodeHandler()?

Comment: I could be wrong but I believe you need to put it before the InitializeComponent()  in your constructor. Also, you are not showing where the ColorHandler is defined. Could you please show that?

Comment: Sorry, copied the wrong 2 functions! I updated my code

Comment: you can't use async/await in a constructor

Comment: Yeah I know, I haven't done that ?

Comment: try putting .Wait() on your ColorHandler call like ColorHandler().Wait();

Comment: Tried that, but I think it gets stuck in an endless loop, because after that it won't hit the next line!?

Comment: Adding `.Wait()` or `.Result` here won't do any good here. You are essentially going to block the UI thread while waiting. Doing so the task cannot get back to the context it came from, since the internals are not called with `.ConfigureAwait(false)`. Make your Rest call in a page lifecycle method instead, then invalidate the Skia view you are using when it is done.

Comment: What do you mean with: "Make your Rest call in a page lifecycle method"?

Comment: he means use OnAppearing

Comment: Or try using async factory method
```public static async Task<DeviceControl> CreateAsync(...)
    {
        DeviceControl x = new DeviceControl();
        await x.ColorHandler(...)
        return x;
    }```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Xamarin can't handle asynchronous await calls in the constructor and as such it will complete before the asynchronous call will.

In fact you need to be careful when calling asynchronous / long running functions in anything relating to the UI as you can end up with deadlocks or slow UI interaction if your trying to force usage of a result.

I would suggest that you change your code such that this function is called before you require it or at the very least don't allow any function that relies upon its results to run until it has done so.

Comment: Thank you, I found a way that I already got the data, before entering the page! I called the webpage while on the homepage, without waiting on it, because I don't need it yet!